# How to use py2exe when it include sklearn?

Tags: python, py2exe

if the code has `import sklearn`, after use `py2exe`

then run the "exe" file, I got this error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "HelloSklearn.py", line 17, in <module>
File "sklearn\__init__.pyc", line 32, in <module>
File "sklearn\base.pyc", line 8, in <module>
File "scipy\sparse\__init__.pyc", line 191, in <module>
File "scipy\sparse\csgraph\__init__.pyc", line 146, in <module>
File "scipy\sparse\csgraph\_shortest_path.pyc", line 12, in <module>
File "scipy\sparse\csgraph\_shortest_path.pyc", line 10, in __load
File "_shortest_path.pyx", line 18, in init scipy.sparse.csgraph._shortest_path(scipy\sparse\csgraph\_shortest_path.c:14235)
ImportError: No module named _validation
```

Comment: This could becaused by py2exe not importing scipy modules.

Comment: maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215303/scipy-with-py2exe) can help you out

Answer (score 4):

You can either add `scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation` to the `includes` option in your `setup.py` script

```
setup( 
    ...
    options = { 'includes': ['scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation'] }
)
```

or just force `py2exe` to spot it by forcing an import - somewhere in your code put

```
import scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation
```