# py2exe with scipy.sparse.sparsetools.csr

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, py2exe

I get the following error message using python v2.7.3 and scipy v0.11.0 with py2exe v0.6.9:

ImportError: No module named _csr

my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe


setup(console=['demo.py'],
  options = {
             "py2exe": {"includes":["scipy.sparse", "scipy.sparse.sparsetools.csr",
                                    "scipy.sparse.sparsetools._csr"]}
             })
```

The question in  [scipy with py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215303/scipy-with-py2exe)
couldn't helped me out.

Comment: @snowBaliz: which operating system that you are using

Comment: @usernaveen: I use Windows 8 64-Bit and tested it on a 64-bit Windows 7 System too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons I can think of for why you might have gotten this error.

1. `_csr.pyd` should normally live in `\Python2.7\Lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\sparsetools`. It is possible that for some reason it is not there - an easy fix could be to reinstall `Scipy`.
2. During the call to `setup`, a `scipy.sparse.sparsetools._csr.py` file is generated. This file makes a call to `imp.load_dynamic`, attempting to load the PYD file. This function can throw an `ImportError`, which could be a symptom of a missing file.

If this does not resolve the problem, it would be great if you could post the output (i.e., what gets printed to the DOS prompt) of `python setup.py py2exe` - this should help narrow things down.

Comment: I dont know why it works now, I compiled my executable again. Manually repacked the library.zip and now it works. Finally :)