# Python/SciPy - Creating an executable

Tags: python, scipy, py2exe, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I have a short python-script that uses SciPy, which runs perfect, but I have trouble converting it into an executable.
I use Windows 7 64bit and Python 2.7, with the Numpy/SciPy Version from Christoph Golke ( http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs, cx_freeze and py2exe also downloaded there ), everything 64bit. 64bit is needed because of the 32bit 4GB RAM-limitation.

I tried several things: pyinstaller, py2exe and cx_freeze (again 64bit). Every time I run the executable, there is an "Import Error: No module named XXX", where XXX equals different things (_validation,_csr,None,multiarray). 
With py2exe, I managed it to get an "ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application".

I searched for this kind of errors and tried including different modules (again with all three scripts mentioned above), but still, same errors.

My Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# easy.py

import scipy as sp
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

rate,data = sp.io.wavfile.read('2.wav')
if data.ndim >= 2:
    data = data[ : ,0]
min = data.min()
if min < 0:
    data= np.multiply(data,0.5)
    data= np.add(data,min/-2)

rate2,data2 = sp.io.wavfile.read('MVI_1849.wav')
if data2.ndim >= 2:
    data2 = data2[ : ,0]
min2 = data2.min()
if min2 < 0:
    data2= np.multiply(data2,0.5)
    data2= np.add(data2,min2/-2)
data2=data2[::-1]

corr = signal.fftconvolve(data,data2)
max = np.argmax(corr)
offset = float(max-len(data2)) / float(rate)

print(offset)
```

I read that this has to do with the import mechanism of NumPy/SciPy, but i have no clue how to fix it.
If you need more information, let me know.
Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

From a little googling around it seems that this is a bug in py2exe with scipy the suggested solution is to import the scipy modules manually:

```
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import _validation
```

Have a look here:
[scipy with py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215303/scipy-with-py2exe)

hope this works in your case.

Comment: I did this, and then the other Error appeared: "ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application". I have everything 64bit and checked the following 3 threads(first 3 results): http://tinyurl.com/cva3mj6

Comment: Why don't you try and load all your dependencies for Scipy manually?