# Unable to freeze application when vispy/scipy in use

Tags: python, scipy, pyside, cx-freeze, vispy

I have an application in which I added a module that plots data using `vispy` and `scipy` (for Delaunay). 
It works fine when I run within the Python (3.4 x64 on Windows) interpreter, but not when frozen using `cx_freeze`. It does not give me any error message, simply it does not run (quietly).

Here my `cx_freeze` script:

```
buildOptions = dict(packages = ['osgeo._gdal', 'scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation'])

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [
    Executable('main.py', base=base, targetName = 'myApp.exe', icon='ico/myApp.ico')
    ]

setup(name='MyApp',
  version = '0.0.1',
  description = 'My fancy app',
  author = 'xxxx@xxxx.xxx',
  options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
  executables = executables)
```

I have to add `'scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation'` to fix a previous missing inclusion as suggested here: [scipy with py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14215303/2741329) and [here](http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/596)

Looking for DLL issues, I have already attempted with Dependency Walker but without luck.

If I comment out the module with the `vispy` plot, everything works fine. Any hint?

Comment: Can somebody with enough reputation create a tag for `vispy`? I believe that will be quite popular in a near future..

Comment: the tag was created!

Comment: Freezing code using scipy is a mess at present - there's [an issue open](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/43/import-errors-when-using-cx_freeze-with) for it. I'm hoping to make things better for the next release of cx_Freeze, but finding the time to work on it is tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have attempted to freeze just the module with the problem by adding a `main` with a `QApplication` that display the `QWigdet` with the `vispy.app.canvas`. This helped because I got a very useful backtrace error related to `vispy.app.backends._pyside`.

After explicitly adding this to my posted `cx_freeze` script, the frozen application works:

```
packages = ['osgeo._gdal', 'vispy.app.backends._pyside', 'scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation']
```

The difference that I found in the build directory is the presence of `QtOpenGL4.dll` and `PySide.QtOpenGL.pyd`. They were not there without the explicit package inclusion (my application was already using PySide).

Answer (score 1):

We've not thought about freezing apps with Vispy much yet. The pitfall that I'd expect matches with gmas80's answer; Vispy can use multiple backends, which means that these are dynamically loaded and cx_Freeze is unable to select the backend modules as a dependency. Depending on the backend that you need, you need to add some modules in `vispy.backends` to the list of includes.