# Script with scipy using py2exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I have ran into this during exporting my script (which uses `numpy` and `scipy` libraries) via `py2exe`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "imPok.py", line 3, in <module>
File "scipy\misc\__init__.pyc", line 49, in <module>
File "scipy\special\__init__.pyc", line 603, in <module>
File "scipy\special\basic.pyc", line 18, in <module>
File "scipy\special\orthogonal.pyc", line 101, in <module>
File "scipy\linalg\__init__.pyc", line 188, in <module>
File "scipy\linalg\_decomp_update.pyc", line 12, in <module>
File "scipy\linalg\_decomp_update.pyc", line 10, in __load
File "scipy/linalg/_decomp_update.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.linalg._decomp_update (scipy\linalg\_decomp_update.c:35768)
ImportError: No module named cython_blas
```

**Tried:**

- installing cython - no use
- removing `scipy` dependencies - that worked, i.e. the trouble is in cooperation between `scipy` and `py2exe`.
- applying the solution of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215303/scipy-with-py2exe) - no use

**Questions:**

- how can I make that work?
- what I should/shouldn't do in general to avoid this problems?

**Appendix:**

These are the problematic lines:

```
from scipy.misc import imread
import numpy as np
```

I actually haven't ask for `scipy.linalg` and `scipy.special` and yet the `py2exe` wants them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this problem today, and found a more thorough solution from [here](https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2005-July/004724.html).

```
opts = {"py2exe": {
    "includes": ['scipy', 'scipy.integrate', 'scipy.special.*','scipy.linalg.*']}}
```

Then, in your setup.py script, use:

```
setup(options=opts,windows=['script.py'])
```

Answer (score 3):

`scipy.misc` must have `scipy.linalg.cython_blas` as a dependency. To solve this include the following package in your py2exe setup script at the "options > include" level:

```
scipy.linalg.cython_blas
```