# Py2Exe - Addressing NumPy and SciPy dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, py2exe

**Objective (End-Goal):**
I want to create a stand-alone executable Python script (*only* one file) that includes NumPy and SciPy dependencies for my application.

**Background:**
From my understanding, to create an executable script in Python - there are three options that are available:

1. PyInstaller
2. Py2exe
3. CxFreeze

I went ahead and tried Py2exe for my development. It appears that CxFreeze does not support the single-file option (from the documentation [here](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html)). I also considered the option of using PyInstaller, but ran into issues regarding missing DLLs (similar to what is found [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1840)). The issue continued to persist even after installing the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package in my laptop.

I followed the tutorial to use Py2exe [here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) and was able to get a dummy script executable (Hello World!) working. However, I tried to re-modify the setup.py script specific to my application to include numpy and scipy dependencies (see below):

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe,sys,numpy,scipy

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
console=['Application.py'],
options={
  'py2exe': {
     'includes':['numpy','scipy','scipy.integrate','scipy.special.*','scipy.linalg.*'],
     'bundle_files':1,
     'compressed':True
  }
},
zipfile=None)
```

This is the resulting error I received when I tried running the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_run_in_console.py", line 52, in run_file
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "C:/Users/prest/PycharmProjects/Application/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
zipfile=None
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 149, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Users\prest\PycharmProjects\Application\venv\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 188, in run
self._run()
File "C:\Users\prest\PycharmProjects\Application\venv\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 267, in _run
builder.analyze()
File "C:\Users\prest\PycharmProjects\Application\venv\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 164, in analyze
mf.import_hook(modname)
File "C:\Users\prest\PycharmProjects\Application\venv\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
module = self._gcd_import(name)
File "C:\Users\prest\PycharmProjects\Application\venv\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
return self._find_and_load(name)
File "C:\Users\prest\PycharmProjects\Application\venv\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 337, in _find_and_load
raise ImportError(name)
ImportError: scipy.linalg.*
```

These are the versions that I am using relevant for my application:

1. Python 3.4
2. NumPy 1.14.5
3. SciPy 1.1.0

**Question:**
Can anyone provide any insight as to why I am receiving this error and any next steps to address this? I appreciate any input!

Thanks,

Preston

Comment: It's been a long time since I did this, but don't you have to list all of the scipy modules you're using in `includes`, not just `scipy`? (Or maybe you can do `scipy.*` or something like that; I can't remember for sure…)

Comment: Hi abamert, I do believe that you have to include the different scipy modules (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754772/script-with-scipy-using-py2exe)). I attempted to try different permutations for the `includes` parameter from the provided post (`scipy.*`,`scipy.integrate`,`scipy.special.*` etc.) and I am getting a `raise ImportError(name)` error. Hmmmm...

Comment: OK, so this question as posted has an easy solution, but that just leads you to a new problem? It's up to you whether you want to close this one and post a new one with the details of that new problem, or edit this one, but either way, you're going to need to give us those details, not these ones, to get an answer to the new problem.

Comment: I updated this post with details of the new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing - went ahead and use PyInstaller for the single-file executable. I re-modified my script to address specific dependencies (only used NumPy).